# Rails redirecting after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect

So on my application home page, there are a variety of actions that can be called via ajax requests.  When a user is signed in, those calls can be made.  When a user is not signed in, I would like to redirect the user to the sign in page if they click on any of those links that go to ajax calls.

In my sessions_helper, I have a method that is used as a before_filter in the controller for these actions.

```
  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end
```

But the redirect does not work on those calls, because the calls are made via ajax. (For the record, it does work on non-ajax calls) For example:

```
<%= link_to new_picture_path, remote: true  do %>
  Add New
<% end %>
```

Is there a way to get this redirect to work via ajax?  I am using rails v3.2.8, and jquery.  I tried adding the following method to my application controller, as a few other posts suggested:

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
  if request.xhr?
    render(:update) {|page| page.redirect_to(options)}
  else
    super(options, response_status)
  end
end
```

But I get an error: "MissingTemplate pictures/update".  And I think some of those other posts indicate it is because i am using jquery and not prototype.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work because the ajax call will be redirected, but your page is already loaded and the redirection won't impact it.

Remove the custom redirect_to, this will not help you.

You have to check if your ajax call returned a 302, then you can redirect the user using javascript with window.location for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can  specify the document.location.href in your JavaScript code

document.location.href = 'what/you/want';

Answer (score 0):

you can create hidden paragraph and pass value from controller, and through js check if that p contains specified word, if does redirect wherever you want

```
def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      @redirect = 'redirect'
    end
  end
```

in your html.erb

```
<p class='hide'><%= @redirect %> </p>
```

and in js file

```
if ($('.hide').text() == 'redirect'){
//do the thing
}
```

maybe little bit messy but efficient way to redirect